# How do I find next row in Postgres based on previous Id?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sql-order-by, where-clause

Suppose I have a table like this:

```
Id  Name
----------
1   John
2   Mary
5   Jason
6   Amit
7   Daniel
10  Emma
11  Max
15  Sachin
```

I'm trying to create a query where I will pass one id and get the next row from the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter on `id`s that are greater than your parameter, order by `id` and retain the first row only, using `limit`:

```
select t.* from mytable t where id > ? order by id limit 1
```

This gives you the record with the next higher `id` to the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this

```
select * from table_name where id = (select min(id) from table_name where id > {Id})
```

This will return you the next available row present in the table